# How do I count words in a PDF file on OS X?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I'd like to count words on a PDF file on OS X. The inspector doesn't contain the word count.

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that many PDF files are collections of images not of text so the word count would be  0 or very low.

Comment: One possibility is to attempt to export the PDF to text, and do the word count there. This is actually also what one would do using Acrobat.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the GhostScript tool [ps2ascii](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps2ascii),

```
$ ps2ascii MSWiM_2016.pdf | wc -w
*** Warning: composite font characters dumped without decoding.
    8964
```

Comment: tried to use ps2ascii command on my laptop running High Sierra (10.13.6) and terminal returned -bash: ps2ascii: command not found.

Comment: Same here – tried `which ps2ascii` on Mojave (10.14.5) and got nothing.

Comment: @HeidiBHarley @AlexRyan, try `pip install ps2ascii`.

Comment: `ps2ascii` is part of GhostScript and not a built-in MacOS tool.

Comment: @benwiggy thx for this update.

Answer (score 2):

Simply open it in Microsoft Word and the word count appears at the bottom:
[image]

Word's File/Properties/Statistics also has more statistics:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I put together a small GUI app ["PDF Word Counter"](https://github.com/ezgranet/pdfwordcounter), which returns the word count for inputted PDF files.  It has no advantage over the other answer (ps2ascii) in terms of the word count returned, but it can be a good solution for those people who don't like to use the command line.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source tool called [PDFbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html) (from Apache) that has some command line tools that you can use to extract the text so that it can be counted with `wc`.  The command (because it's a Java jar) would be as follows:

```
% java -jar pdfbox.jar ExtractText -console foobar.pdf | wc -w
```

`-console` is required because it will automatically write a text file with the same base name as the source (i.e. `foobar.pdf` → `foobar.txt`)

This option is much smaller that what's included with Ghostscript, though it does require a JRE (Java Run Time Environment) installed though that's [pretty easy to do](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk-jre-macos-catalina.html).

---

It's available via [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/pdfbox/summary) or directly from source.  It's a Java jar file, so I suggest copying it to `/usr/local/bin/` and creating an alias to it for convenience

```
alias pdfbox="java -jar /usr/local/bin/pdfbox.jar"
```

Put that alias in your shell profile - `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zprofile` for Bash or Zsh respectively.  Then you can issue the command as follows:

```
% pdfbox ExtractText -console foobar.pdf | wc -w
```