# Word count pdf in Mojave?

Tags: mojave, pdf

Is there anyway to count words in a pdf document on Mojave?, it is not in 'get info' when right clicking and preview doesn't seem to have a tool for it.

thanks for your time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I count words in a PDF file on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252362/how-do-i-count-words-in-a-pdf-file-on-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third-party application if you are not familiar with terminal.

[Pdfwordcounter](https://github.com/ezgranet/pdfwordcounter) which returns the word count for inputted PDF files.